# Kubernetes custom CA and certificate between proxy service and deployment

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, proxy, certificate

My Kubernetes cluster has 2 applications.

- A deployment connecting to an external API through `https://` - lets call it `Fetcher`
- A proxy service which terminates the `HTTPs` request to inspect the headers for rate limiting - called `Proxy`

The deployment uses the mentioned proxy, picture the following architecture

`Fetcher deployment <-- private network / Kubernetes --> Proxy <-- Internet --> external API`

Before I moved to Kubernetes this was solved by creating a self-signed certificate and certificate authority CA to trust and place them on the Fetcher and proxy. The certificate simply contained the IP address of docker as SAN.

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com, DNS:mail.example.com, DNS:ftp.example.com, IP Address:192.168.99.100, IP Address:192.168.56.1, IP Address:192.168.2.75
```

However I can't do this in Kubernetes, can I? Since the IP addresses of both the deployment and service are not guaranteed, the IP's could change. I am using a Kubernetes `CoreDNS` solution, could I add the dns addresses in the certificate? I dont know enough about `ssl/certificates` to understand.

How can I create a certificate and CA in Kubernetes to create a trust between the certificate sent by the proxy with a custom certificate authority on the fetcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expose the proxy deployment via a service, then by default it will be assigned a `ClusterIP` which will be stable even as the IPs of the pods running the proxy may change over time. You will want to generate a cert with an IPSAN corresponding to the `ClusterIP` of the service, rather than any of the IPs of the pods. Check out the [official docs regarding the "service" concept](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

Comment: Sometimes somebody just needs too point out the obvious answer to a noob. Its all working. Ive added the service in the certificates as its dns record and the rest as the clusterIP. Thanks a lot!